# MySQL Stored Procedure and Cursor

Tags: mysql, cursor

I'm a beginner in stackoverflow and I hope that you gives me the solution for my problem, I'll explain :

I have two table : 
the first table (table A) contains (phone number, duration) and 
the second table (table B) contains (internationnal_prefix,destination, fee per minute,and length(prefix))

So what I need to do is making this update for all the data in the two table, i'll explain the algorithm after, first of all this is the update commmand :
/* We'll add a column in the table A that will contains our result, we name it "result" */

```
 UPDATE table Table A SET result  = CASE WHEN left (phone_number,length(prefix)) = prefix_inter 
  THEN  (duration * fee per minute)
```

This is what I want to do **for every phone number**, 
I have already **ordered the table B by prefix** *to have the largest prefix on the top* so that the first checked is the largest code.

This code will calculate the consommation of the VOIP, so we need to detect the destination from he phone number by verifying if the phone number contains exactly the internationnal prefix or not (for example we can have 0044123 with 0.156€ per minute  and 0044 for 0.08€ per minute, this is why we must begin with the largest code in the verification)

**Every phone number must be verified with all the prefix in table B**
So finally, I need you to give me the solution cause I don't have enough knowledge in this domain...

*PS:I'm using MySQL 5.5*
Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want to calculate the price of a phone call using these two tables? One way you can do it is by looking up the fee per minute in a subselect:

```
UPDATE A SET result = (select A.duration*B.fee_per_minute from B where
    locate(B.prefix, A.phone_number) = 1 order by length(prefix) desc limit 1);
```

If B is already ordered by the prefix length you can drop the "order by".

Comment: Thanks for your Code Joni but I'm getting this error : ERROR[1093] You can't specify target table 'dump_test' for update in FROM clause –

Comment: What does your SQL look like?

Comment: I should tell you that I don't have any relation between table A and Table B, abput your question "What does my SQL look like?" ...sorry but I didn't undestand this ...

Comment: I mean that there's something wrong with the syntax of the UPDATE statement that you have written. What I posted works, once you create tables A and B with the relevant columns.

Comment: Ok now there is no error in the code , but There is no changes in the tables...any advices please ?

Comment: You should open a new question and post details of the tables involved--preferably the CREATE TABLE statements--and the UPDATE statement that's giving you the error. There's not enough information to help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help Joni :) What I have already heard of StackovrFlow is 100% correct ! This is more than a website, this is an awsome community :) Thanks again.